# WebRTC microphone issue in Android 10

Tags: android, audio, webrtc, microphone

Device in question:

- DJI RC Pro Enterprise used for controlling enterprise DJI drones
- OS is Android 10, probably running stock Android as there's no Google Play services on the device

When establishing a WebRTC session as a master from Android 10 mobile device, the audio that should be gathered via microphone is not getting through to the viewer side. When I'm configuring transceiver on the viewer side, I do enforce both send & receive for the audio part via:

```
viewer.peerConnection.addTransceiver('audio', {direction: 'sendrecv'});
```

Also looking at `chrome://webrtc-internals` tab, it clearly shows (`inbound-rtp` stats for `audio`) that audio channel is open and some small amount of data is coming through:
[image]

But clearly we can spot that:

1. Bytes received in bits/s are only around 3k, where another Android device that is using newer Android version and the microphone sound is actually coming through on the viewer side is hitting around 30k bits/s.
2. Audio level is staying at 0 regardless how loud I speak into the microphone.

Here's also the stats from inbound-rtc in text:

```
inbound-rtp (kind=audio, mid=4, ssrc=3185575416, [codec]=opus (111, minptime=10;useinbandfec=1), id=IT31A3185575416)
Statistics IT31A3185575416
timestamp   2/16/2023, 2:51:44 PM
ssrc    3185575416
kind    audio
trackId DEPRECATED_TI8
transportId T31
codecId CIT31_111_minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
[codec] opus (111, minptime=10;useinbandfec=1)
mediaType   audio
jitter  0.063
packetsLost 0
trackIdentifier efe06737-ed24-448c-bf32-d002cef9171b
mid 4
packetsReceived 170
[packetsReceived/s] 13.550688631363338
packetsDiscarded    0
fecPacketsReceived  0
fecPacketsDiscarded 0
bytesReceived   5524
[bytesReceived_in_bits/s]   3523.179044154468
headerBytesReceived 4760
[headerBytesReceived_in_bits/s] 3035.354253425388
lastPacketReceivedTimestamp 1676555504833
[lastPacketReceivedTimestamp]   2/16/2023, 2:51:44 PM
jitterBufferDelay   77020.8
[jitterBufferDelay/jitterBufferEmittedCount_in_ms]  0
jitterBufferTargetDelay 270316.8
jitterBufferMinimumDelay    270240
jitterBufferEmittedCount    153600
totalSamplesReceived    665760
[totalSamplesReceived/s]    48782.47907290802
concealedSamples    505242
[concealedSamples/s]    48782.47907290802
[concealedSamples/totalSamplesReceived] 1
silentConcealedSamples  482592
[silentConcealedSamples/s]  48782.47907290802
concealmentEvents   14
insertedSamplesForDeceleration  6960
[insertedSamplesForDeceleration/s]  0
removedSamplesForAcceleration   0
[removedSamplesForAcceleration/s]   0
audioLevel  0
totalAudioEnergy    0
[Audio_Level_in_RMS]    0
totalSamplesDuration    13.869999999999749
jitterBufferFlushes*    2
delayedPacketOutageSamples* 452322
relativePacketArrivalDelay* 718.31
interruptionCount*  10
totalInterruptionDuration*  9.197
remoteId    ROA3185575416
```

We have confirmed that microphone works on this device using third party tool microphone test app or just simply doing screen recording. We've also made sure on the master side that correct mode is set and that microphone is not muted via:

```
audioManager.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,
                    AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);

// Start by setting MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION as default audio mode. It is
// required to be in this mode when playout and/or recording starts for
// best possible VoIP performance.
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(false);
```

Also using this method to check if microphone is available just before the start of the streaming returns `True`:

```
public static boolean getMicrophoneAvailable(Context context) {
        MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setOutputFile(new File(context.getCacheDir(), "MediaUtil#micAvailTestFile").getAbsolutePath());
        boolean available = true;
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
            recorder.start();

        }
        catch (Exception exception) {
            available = false;
        }
        recorder.release();
        return available;
    }
```

The questions are therefore the following:

- Does somehow running stock Android without Google Play services impact the usage of microphone in the WebRTC streaming session? I'm basing this assumption that Google is the main developer behind WebRTC and perhaps they've built some features around their Google Play services library
- Given that microphone is clearly available, could I manually start the recording and started sending the audio bits via open WebRTC audio channel?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but just wanted to share my experience. I was working a while back on a flutter WebRTC application and had the same issue trying to start mic or camera without the play store on the emulator. I had found an answer at the time why certain features only work on the images with the play store but I cannot recall the "why".

Comment: So it might be connected to the missing Google Play services in the end?

Comment: @Jermej Jerin If memory serves, yes. It's been months, so I could be wrong. But switching to an emulator image with the play services resolved all of my problems getting mic or cam to start.